# How to specify column names in Hibernate/JPA when inheritance is involved?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, groovy

I think I'm trying to have my cake and eat it too here, but we'll see if there's a plausible solution to what I'm looking for. I have a Spring Boot/JPA/Hibernate app that will be talking to MySQL as its backing store. I have several cases where my entity classes form, from an OOP perspective, a parent/child hierarchy like so:

```
// Groovy pseudo-code!
class Vehicle {
  Long id
  Long maxSpeed
  String make
  String model
}

class Motorcycle extends Vehicle {
  Boolean isTwoStroke
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
  Boolean hasLeatherInterior
}
```

etc. Normally, outside of JPA, I might design their respective tables like so:

```
CREATE TABLE motorcycles (
  motorcycle_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  motorcycle_max_speed BIGINT UNSIGNED,
  motorcycle_make VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  motorcycle_model VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  motorcycle_is_two_speed BIT NOT NULL,

  # PK, FK, UC, index constraints down here (omitted for brevity)
);

CREATE TABLE cars (
  car_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  car_max_speed BIGINT UNSIGNED,
  car_make VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  car_model VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  car_has_leather_interior BIT NOT NULL,

  # PK, FK, UC, index constraints down here (omitted for brevity)
);
```

**Ideally** I'd like to keep this table design as-is, with the names of the "parent vehicle" columns staying exactly as I have the, above. But if I'm understanding the Hibernate/JPA APIs correctly, then I don't *think* its possible without making some sort of sacrifice. I think I either need to sacrifice inheritance at the app-layer so that I can name the columns in the child classes exactly as I have them in the DB:

```
@Entity
class Motorcycle {    // No longer extends Vehicle :-(
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "motorcycle_id")
  Long id

  @Column(name = "motorcycle_max_speed")
  Long maxSpeed

  @Column(name = "motorcycle_make")
  String make

  @Column(name = "motorcycle_model")
  String model

  @Column(name = "motorcycle_is_two_speed")
  Boolean isTwoStroke
}

@Entity
class Car {    // No longer extends Vehicle :-(
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "car_id")
  Long id

  @Column(name = "car_max_speed")
  Long maxSpeed

  @Column(name = "car_make")
  String make

  @Column(name = "car_model")
  String model

  @Column(name = "car_has_leather_interior")
  Boolean hasLeatherInterior
}
```

**Or** I think I can keep app-layer inheritance, but then would need to refactor my DB tables like so:

```
CREATE TABLE motorcycles (
  id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  max_speed BIGINT UNSIGNED,
  make VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  model VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  motorcycle_is_two_speed BIT NOT NULL,

  # PK, FK, UC, index constraints down here (omitted for brevity)
);

CREATE TABLE cars (
  id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  max_speed BIGINT UNSIGNED,
  make VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  model VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  car_has_leather_interior BIT NOT NULL,

  # PK, FK, UC, index constraints down here (omitted for brevity)
);
```

So I ask: is it possible for me to keep my app-layer inheritance (and have `Motorcycle` and `Car` inherit those properties from `Vehicle`) **and** keep my DB table columns named using my preferred convention?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can possible with @MappedSuperclass (`Designates a class whose mapping information is applied to the entities that inherit from it. A mapped superclass
has no separate table defined for it.`)
Vehicle class :

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Vehicle {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;
    Long maxSpeed;
    String make;
    String model;
}
```

Motorcycle subclass

```
 @Entity
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "motorcycle_id"))
    })
    public class Motorcycle extends Vehicle {
        Boolean isTwoStroke;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Bhushan Uniyal (+1) - one quick followup question if you don't mind: I plan on creating my own DB first and then use `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = validate` (instead of `create` or something else). I also plan on setting up my primary keys in MySQL as being `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns. If MySQL PKs are already auto-incrementing, and if I'm having Hibernate simply `validate` my existing DB, do I even need to specify `@GeneratedValue` on my PK fields in the code? Thanks again!

Comment: @smeeb yes you can remove @GeneratedValue, it will work  without it because you are useing `AUTO_INCREMEN` enabling  in database level.  also  `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = validate`  will take care of your db schema so no issue here