# (JPA) Can a sub entity have the same properties as abstract entity but with different names?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an abstract class, that maps let the column "year" to a variable called "year".

One of my subclass also needs that same variable from the same column "year" but it needs to be called for instance "creation year" instead. How can I do this ?

I have some problems as I can't change at all the state of the database and it is ANCIENT, as it dates back to the 80s...

Which is also why in that case one table is holding things that are completely different, even though they are in one table only.

So for instance one line in the database may define a car, in which case column year should be visible as "creation year" and another line may define an explosion, in such case that same column year should be visible as "detonation date".

I am trying to map this database via JPA and hibernate so I can finally distinguish what is what, I just need this tiny difference to complete my project, so if someone has the solution it would be marvelous.

Here is an example code to go with the question (do not bother with the types they are just random):

```
//Mother class
@Entity
@Table(name = "MYTABLE")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="MY_COL_A", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Mother implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String id, year;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "IDA")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "MY_YEAR")
    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
}

//Daughter class
@Entity(name="Sub")
@DiscriminatorValue("MY_VALUE")
public class Sub extends Mother implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1.1L;

    // What I would like to have
    private String creationYear;

    // code here to link creationYear to Mother.year 
    // so it is the same value at the end but with different name
}
```

Thank you for your help !

EDIT: This question is different from [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43263302) as in this one the programmer needs to have the same value ID pointing to two different columns in the case of car id points to column car_id and in the case of motorcycle the id points to motorcycle_id.

My problem here is to have two fields in each class with different names pointing to the same column in the database,

Comment: Why don't you simply add a getter/setter-pair "getCreationYear/setCreationYear" to "Sub" which accesses the "year" internally?

Comment: Because then when I show a json of the sub class for instance I have a year and a creation year which is a redundant information. The year column would need to be hidden somehow

Comment: So, when serializing the object why not simply skip "year"?

Comment: To further improve usability, you may also make any accessors of "year" protected for example, so nobody outside of your class hierarchy may access it.

Comment: You could use @JsonIgnore for year to hide it in json.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify column names in Hibernate/JPA when inheritance is involved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43263302/how-to-specify-column-names-in-hibernate-jpa-when-inheritance-is-involved)

Comment: @Augusto it is different in the question you show me the guy has two columns and want to have the name ID so he points to another column in the motocycle class... In my case I have one table only, where let say the name of the column (its header) should change according to the line I am reading

Comment: @Smutje thanks for the protected indeed it is better, I could then skip year i will try that and see